# YouTube Data API: recordingDetails not available after uploading a video via YouTube uploader

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I uploaded my `.mov` file via the standard YouTube Upload (https://www.youtube.com/upload).
The video does contain the geolocation data and the date created, I have confirmed with `exiftool`.

However, `recordingDetails` does not come through when testing via https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it.

1. Does YouTube strip out the `recordingDetails` if I upload the video at https://www.youtube.com/upload?
2. Are there restrictions on video types, privacy settings, or anything else that would prevent `recordingDetails` from being available?
3. Or, if put differently, are `recordingDetails`details only available if I manually provide them via my own API upload script?

I'm using a client-side only framework, and trying to accomplish this without relying on a server script that would parse the geolocation from the video.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `recordingDetails` will only be returned with the videos that have set a recording time. I [tried different videoId](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=recordingDetails&id=mHcQHT8hiS4&_h=5&) and I cannot get any result with it. So meaning if the video doesn't have the attributes for it, then the API will not return any data.

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1Video.html), the `recordingDetails` object encapsulates information about the location, date and address where the video was recorded. So you need to manually include it in the video for you to fetch this information.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, `recordingDetails` JSON field will not be present if there are no children values.
Are you saying that the DATE/TIME of the recording must always be present too, for the entire `recordingDetails` to come back, including the geolocation data?
I had explored the docs extensively before asking this question, and yes, if I upload the video through API while setting the `recordingDetails` explicitly, they do become available.
My question is more about the regular, non-API, upload to YouTube, which seems to not preserve the `recordingDetails`.